# When source_address of python socket.create_connection is used?

Tags: python, sockets

```
socket.create_connection(address[, timeout[, source_address]])
```

Any example to show the usage of source_address?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My question is clear enough. Now, I know the answer.

I know how to inspect source code, I read the source code of method socket.create_connection(address[, timeout[, source_address]]), I asked for source_address, it's all about binding.
I have this question because I am a beginner, I have no background knowledge of socket programming, so I find a book named "Foundations of Python Network Programming" to read. In chapter 3 TCP, section One Socket per Conversation, i got it and made an example.

```
import socket

baidu = ('www.baidu.com', 80)
zero = ('0.0.0.0', 9001)

def test(addr, src_addr):
    try:
        sock = socket.create_connection(addr, 3, src_addr)
        print sock.getsockname()
        print
        sock.sendall('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        print data
    finally:
        try:
            sock.close()
        except:
            pass

test(baidu, zero)
#test(baidu, None)
```

you can toggle the two test functions to see the differences.

Comment: This is not an answer to anything, much less to your question.

Comment: I will answer it when I know all about it.

Comment: OK… but until then, don't clutter up SO with useless and/or confusing cruft. Delete your answer, and create a new one when you're ready to write one.

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection) says:

> If supplied, `source_address` must be a 2-tuple (`host`, `port`) for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting. If host or port are ‘’ or 0 respectively the OS default behavior will be used.

In other words, it's used when you need to `bind` the socket before connecting. If you don't know why you'd ever need to do that, you don't need to do it. But here's a brief sketch of an example: An FTP server needs to be able to make an outgoing data connection on the same interface as the incoming control connection. You can do that by binding the same local address that the control connection has. So:

```
def make_data_conn(controlconn, port, timeout):
    return socket.create_connection((controlconn.getpeername()[0], port),
                                    timeout,
                                    (controlconn.getsockname()[0], 0))
```

Comment: no need to show me the doc link

Comment: @metaphy: Even if you've read the docs and have them open right in front of you, questions and answers are supposed to be helpful to others who search for similar problems in the future, and many of those people _will_ need the doc link.

Comment: but this question is downvoted,so it is not a helpful question.

Comment: @metaphy Strange attitude. A link to the docs is always helpful in order to make an answer more helpful.

Comment: so search google, you will get clear answers about it.

Comment: @metaphy And how is the answer not helpful because of the downvoted question?!

Comment: I come here from there, anyone who have question about source_address, why didn't you come here from there?

Comment: @metaphy: Well, I didn't downvote the question, and I did try to provide an answer. If _you_ think the people who downvoted your question are right, and the question is not helpful, you should probably close it.

Comment: @metaphy: The return value of `socket.create_connection` is a normal `socket.socket` object, which you close the same way as any other socket: with its `close` method.